# decimal? Nullable object must have a value

Tags: c#

My logic is working fine when the meeting object has values for all FlatFees. But when I remove the FlatFee for some of the Meeting  I get an error `Nullable object must have a value.` I know that I need to check if FlatFee is null but how can I do a select for that?

```
                //EF Data
                List<MeetingEvent> Meeting = new List<MeetingEvent>();
                Meeting.Add(new MeetingEvent() { MeetingId = 1, MeetingName = "A1", FlatFee=25000 });
                Meeting.Add(new MeetingEvent() { MeetingId = 2, MeetingName = "A2", FlatFee = 45000 });
                Meeting.Add(new MeetingEvent() { MeetingId = 3, MeetingName = "A3" });
                Meeting.Add(new MeetingEvent() { MeetingId = 4, MeetingName = "A4" });
                Meeting.Add(new MeetingEvent() { MeetingId = 5, MeetingName = "A5" });
    
                //EF Data
                List<Event> Event = new List<Event>();
                Event.Add(new Event() { EventId=1, MeetingId = 1,  });
                Event.Add(new Event() { EventId = 2, MeetingId = 2,  });
                Event.Add(new Event() { EventId = 3, MeetingId = 3,  });
                Event.Add(new Event() { EventId = 4, MeetingId = 4,  });
                Event.Add(new Event() { EventId = 5, MeetingId = 5,  });
    
                var listOfEvents = Event.Select(y => new MeetingEventViewModel
                {
                    MeetingId = y.MeetingId,
                    FlatFee = Meeting.Where(f => f.MeetingId ==y.MeetingId).Select(s => s.FlatFee.Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                }).ToList();
    
                foreach (MeetingEventViewModel m in listOfEvents)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(m.MeetingId);
                    Console.WriteLine(m.FlatFee);
                }

 class MeetingEvent
        {
            public int MeetingId { get; set; }
            public string MeetingName { get; set; }
            public decimal? FlatFee { get; set; }
        }
        class Event
        {
            public int EventId { get; set; }
            public int MeetingId { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public MeetingEvent MeetingEvent { get; set; }
        }

        class MeetingEventViewModel
        {
            public int MeetingId { get; set; }
            public string MeetingName { get; set; }
            public decimal? FlatFee { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: use `HasValue` to filter not nullable values before getting them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either filter out the null values, so this:

```
FlatFee = Meeting
  .Where(f => f.MeetingId ==y.MeetingId)
  .Select(s => s.FlatFee.Value)
  .FirstOrDefault(),
```

becomes this:

```
FlatFee = Meeting
  .Where(f => f.MeetingId ==y.MeetingId && f.FlatFee.HasValue)
  .Select(s => s.FlatFee.Value)
  .FirstOrDefault(),
```

Or set a default value ('0'?) where FlatFee is `null`, so this:

```
FlatFee = Meeting
  .Where(f => f.MeetingId ==y.MeetingId)
  .Select(s => s.FlatFee.Value)
  .FirstOrDefault(),
```

Becomes this:

```
FlatFee = Meeting
  .Where(f => f.MeetingId ==y.MeetingId)
  .Select(s => s.FlatFee.HasValue ? s.FlatFee.Value : 0)
  .FirstOrDefault(),
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try redefining your model likes this? Idea is FlatFee to have always null value by default.

```
class MeetingEvent
        {
            public int MeetingId { get; set; }
            public string MeetingName { get; set; }
            public decimal? FlatFee { get; set; } = null;
        }
        class Event
        {
            public int EventId { get; set; }
            public int MeetingId { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public MeetingEvent MeetingEvent { get; set; }
        }

        class MeetingEventViewModel
        {
            public int MeetingId { get; set; }
            public string MeetingName { get; set; }
            public decimal? FlatFee { get; set; } = null;
        }
```

Comment: How does that prevent the error when trying to call .Value on a null?

Comment: You are right should have conditional check with .HasValue while making a call.

Answer (score 1):

You can check `FlatFee` that has a value or not. if it does not have a value set `0` instead of `NULL`

```cs
var listOfEvents = Event.Select(y => new MeetingEventViewModel
{
    MeetingId = y.MeetingId,
    FlatFee = Meeting.Where(f => f.MeetingId == y.MeetingId).Select(s => s.FlatFee.HasValue ? s.FlatFee.Value : 0 ).FirstOrDefault(),
}).ToList();
```

or get `FlatFee` records that have value and not `NULL`

```cs
foreach(MeetingEventViewModel m in listOfEvents.Where(m=> m.FlatFee.HasValue))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.MeetingId);
    Console.WriteLine(m.FlatFee);
}
```

Another option is get records that `FlatFee` has a value.
adding `f.FlatFee.HasValue` in **Where**

```cs
var listOfEvents = Event.Select(y => new MeetingEventViewModel
{
    MeetingId = y.MeetingId,
    FlatFee = Meeting.Where(f => f.MeetingId == y.MeetingId && f.FlatFee.HasValue).Select(s => s.FlatFee.Value ).FirstOrDefault(),
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can control with DBNull.Value in Nullable types.

```
  foreach (MeetingEventViewModel m in listOfEvents)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(m.MeetingId);
                        Console.WriteLine(m.FlatFee == DBNull.Value ? 0 : m.FlatFee);
                    }
```

Maybe, it will work for your jobs.

Edit:
If you want to use Console.Writeline.
You should use this m.FlatFee.ToString() Console.WriteLine(m.FlatFee == DBNull.Value ? 0 : m.FlatFee.ToString());
But, if you want a decimal variable, you should convert this value.
Like this;
if(m.FlatFee != DBNull.Value) { flatFee=Convert.ToDecimal(m.FlatFee); }

Comment: Unless I am missing something, the exception is from earlier than this bit.

Comment: what kind of exception are you getting @TobiasKildetoft ?